# geotools - Is it possible to skip columns when inserting new SimpleFeature using JDBCDataStore

Tags: java, geotools

In our application (Java, Geotools 25, PostGIS) we have forms where the user can input some data which will be used to create a new features. In the database (PostGIS) there are more columns than there are fields so some columns will be empty. For some of these 'empty' columns there are default values defined in the database. Geotools however seems to always insert null for these columns.

In code I have a `SimpleFeatureStore` and I create a `SimpleFeature` based on the user input. When I'm inserting new Features (`store.addFeatures()`) the final SQL that is created by Geotools is an `INSERT INTO` statement which contains `null` values for all the columns which are not 'in the form', but again some of these have default values in the DB. Since Geotools explicitly sets the value to `null` the default value is never used.

Is there a fix or workaround I can try to resolve this issue so I can just let the DB insert default values when no value is supplied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataUtilities` class provides a [`defaultValues(SimpleFeatureType )`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/de6f05cd4ef69523e6ff14e4658d3db92e740b10/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/DataUtilities.java#L784) method that you can call to get the value defined in the `PropertyDescriptor` (though by default this is null). You can define the default value for any or all of your attributes in your `SimpleFeatureType`.

I would use some code like:

```
SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder sftb = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
sftb.setName("test");
sftb.add("id", Integer.class);
sftb.defaultValue("String");
sftb.add("desc", String.class);
SimpleFeatureType schema = sftb.buildFeatureType();
SimpleFeatureBuilder sfb = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(schema);
sfb.addAll(DataUtilities.defaultValues(schema));
sfb.set("id", 23);
SimpleFeature f = sfb.buildFeature("test.1");
System.out.println(f);
```

Which produces a feature like:

```
SimpleFeatureImpl:test=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: id<id id=test.1>=23,
 SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: desc<desc id=test.1>=String]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I don't think this will work in my case since the default values are defined in the database itself on various columns and not in code. Looking at the code of the JDBCDataStore I'm not seeing a way to prevent `null` inserts for empty columns since the DataStore reads the definition for the SimpleFeatureType from the DB. Therefor I cannot change the columns being inserted or the default values that are used

Comment: well you could read the defaults out of the DB table when you build the schema

Comment: In the end we went for a workaround in the DB using triggers. Will mark this answer as accepted since it helped us a find our solution.